# Ghostscript outputs blank pdf

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript, imagick, cmyk

I'm using following command in PHP to convert a PDF with RBG colors to CMYK colors:

```
$input  = PDF_DIR . 'input.pdf';
$output = PDF_DIR . 'output.pdf'

exec("'gs'
      '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite'
      '-dUseCIEColor'
      '-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK'
      '-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK'
      '-sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK'
      '-sOutputFile=$output'
      '$input'
");
```

I am using Ghostscript version 8.71.

```
gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 8.71 (2010-02-10)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

Somehow the result is always an empty pdf file. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any answers, Cheers!

Some references:

- [Script (or some other means) to convert RGB to CMYK in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418268/script-or-some-other-means-to-convert-rgb-to-cmyk-in-pdf)
- [Converting PDF to CMYK (with identify recognizing CMYK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241282/converting-pdf-to-cmyk-with-identify-recognizing-cmyk)
- [PowerBuilder 12.5 Classic GhostScript blank pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370313/powerbuilder-12-5-classic-ghostscript-blank-pdf)
- [PowerBuilder 12.5 Classic PDF SaveAs creating files of 0 size on Win7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853014/powerbuilder-12-5-classic-pdf-saveas-creating-files-of-0-size-on-win7-x64/15854193#15854193)

Comment: Here is an idea: why not put another parameter to exec() for collecting output from GS, then see if GS outputs some error messages?

Comment: This version of GS is very old try using the version 9.06 which is more stable for me than the latest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if I omit the -dUseCIEColor parameter. I also added an parameter to collect the output like Sami Laine suggested. This is my final code:

```
$input  = PDF_DIR . 'input.pdf';
$output = PDF_DIR . 'output.pdf'

exec("'gs'
  '-o $return'
  '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite'
  '-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK'
  '-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK'
  '-sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK'
  '-sOutputFile=$output'
  '$input'
");
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Devs say ([1](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=700819#c1),[2](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693716#c4),[3](https://ghostscript.com/irclogs/2012/11/21.html),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337225/1032586)) that there's no `sColorConversionStrategyForImages` switch.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sami says above (which is excellent advice, you *need* to see the back channel output) you should also upgrade, 8.71 is quite old.